# Spoofing OS userAgent via CUrl; am I approaching this right?

Tags: networking

So my school seems to be shaping traffic based on the OS of a device. For instance, I access a course video on my desktop (windows 8.1) and it works just fine (downloading the video at about 400k/sec) however when I attempt to do the exact same thing on my laptop (mac OSX), I get a choppy video downloading at about 30k/sec.

I **assume** that their is OS based traffic shaping going on (OSX and IOS seem to be too similar for whatever network shaper they are using). I want to **prove** my assumption....

I figure that if I can use `curl` to access the video at `http://school.edu/vid.flv` from within my mac at a speed approaching 400k/sec then I will have effectively proven that my school is shaping traffic based on the OS. My problem is that when I run the following command, I see no different results...

`curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" http://school.edu/vid.flv`

My question then becomes (1) am I using this command and/or method to prove my assumption correctly and then (2) is my assumption wrong? For instance, are they using MAC address filtering instead....

---

NOTE:

- I have already tried all the main browsers and confirmed this behaviour in both OS's (IE all 4 browsers in Windows DL the vid at ~400k/s while all 4 browsers in OSX DL at ~30k/s)
- I have tried using a VPN on both OS's, no effect.
- My IT department denies anything is wrong (even with screenshots) and they also suggest using firefox as the preferred browser (which is why my curl is using mozilla).

Comment: Make sure you're keeping your kilo*bits* and kilo*bytes* straight.  Streaming media rates are usually reported in bits per second, while downloads are usually reported in bytes per second.

Comment: If I were you I'd look at the micro rather than the macro.  Get a packet capture of both types of connection, and see what the difference is in the data flow (packet size, ack behavior, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an InfoSec question. This is kind of simply a networking question.

Comment: If you used a VPN (properly), then you have proven that the problem is local to your machine because they can't inspect your userAgent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you are spoofing your user agent correctly. In many circumstances this is enough.
2. While it may yield some results, I doubt this is your problem. I would instead look into differences in networking implementation, the state of flash on both machines, and intended flash video player in both machines.

Does your school use a custom flash video player applet? If they do, it might be in bad shape, or make assumptions about your browser. In that case, it is not so much that they are limiting you as that they did not check cross browser compatibility correctly.